# elevatezoom on responsive image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, zooming

I'm using [this plugin](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/configuration) to zoom my image on site.

my site is responsive and i try to make the inner zoom responsive as well but it's not working. if i make my window smaller then the inner zoom stay big.

```
<div class="img_container">
    <img id="image1" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSiDXrY6NqEuhZ8yYdpKjAGC9AVQtAL84ldgSmNx71mQoB-TQRW" class="image1">
</div>
```

```js
$('#image1').elevateZoom({
    responsive : true,
    borderSize : 1,
    borderColour : '#ccc',
    zoomType : 'inner',
    cursor: 'crosshair'
});
```

```css
.img_container {
    width: 100%
}
.image1 {
    min-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Actually, now i'm seeing that the plugin is responsive but only on load. If i refresh the page when my browser width is 320px than the inner zoom will be 320px. but if i change the browser size the inner zoom won't change.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item-image").elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "inner",
        cursor: "crosshair",
        easing: true,
    });

    $(window).resize(function(e){
        $('.zoomContainer').remove();
        $(".item-image").elevateZoom({
            zoomType: "inner",
            cursor: "crosshair",
            easing: true,
        });
    }); 
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me by removing and adding the data to $(".active-zoom") :

```
var $zoomImg = $(".active-zoom");

         zoomConfig = { gallery:'thumbnails', 
                        cursor: 'inherit', 
                        galleryActiveClass: 'active', 
                        imageCrossfade: true, 
                        zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
                        zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
                        lensFadeIn: 500,
                        lensFadeOut: 500,
                        borderSize:0,
                        zoomType:'inner',
                        containLensZoom: 1,
                        responsive:true
}

$zoomImg.elevateZoom(zoomConfig); 

$(window).resize(function(){

        var height = $zoomImg.height();

        $(".zoomWrapper").css("height", height);
        $(".zoomContainer .zoomWindow").css({"height": height});

        $zoomImg.removeData('elevateZoom');
        $('.zoomContainer').remove();

        setTimeout(function() {

            $(".active-zoom").elevateZoom(zoomConfig);

            }, 90)

});
```

CSS:

```
img.active-zoom {

        height: auto !important;
        width: 100% !important

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I try the kieran solution, but dont work for me, i work with this

**HTML**

```
<div class="productoImage">
    <h2><p>Titulo</p></h2>
    <img id="imagenPrincipal"/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function setPrincipalImage(imageURL){
        $("#imagenPrincipal").remove();
        $(".zoomContainer").remove();
        var img = $('<img/>');

        img.attr('id','imagenPrincipal');
        img.attr('src',String(imageURL));
        img.attr('data-zoom-image',String(imageURL));

        $('.productoImage').append(img);

         /*ElevateZoom*/
        $("#imagenPrincipal").elevateZoom({
            zoomType: "inner",         
            cursor: "crosshair" ,
            zoomWindowFadeIn: 350,
            zoomWindowFadeOut: 350
        }); 
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var src = $("#imagenPrincipal").attr('src');
        setPrincipalImage(src);
    });
```